# Rails: Added asset path is of type Pathname instead of String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, npm, node-modules

I have added node_nodules to my rails asset paths:

`Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')`

When I look at my rails asset paths using:

`Rails.application.config.assets.path`

I get the following output:

```
["/Users/gerardsimpson/pier/ruby/ies-portal/app/assets/config",
 "/Users/gerardsimpson/pier/ruby/ies-portal/app/assets/images",
 "/Users/gerardsimpson/pier/ruby/ies-portal/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/Users/gerardsimpson/pier/ruby/ies-portal/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/Users/gerardsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts",
 "/Users/gerardsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.1/lib/assets/compiled",
 "/Users/gerardsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.1/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/Users/gerardsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.2.1/lib/assets/compiled",
 "/Users/gerardsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.2.0/lib/assets/javascripts",
 #<Pathname:/Users/gerardsimpson/pier/ruby/ies-portal/node_modules>,
 "/Users/gerardsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/react-rails-2.4.7/lib/assets/react-source/development",
 "/Users/gerardsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/react-rails-2.4.7/lib/assets/javascripts/"]
```

Why is my added path of type `Pathname` instead of type `String` ? will this have any unintended consequences in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is my added path of type Pathname instead of type String ?

Because in Rails 3 and newer [Rails.root](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails.html#method-c-root) returns an object of [Pathname](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) type. Calling [join](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-join) method of that object returns another `Pathname`.

If you want a string you have to add `.to_s`:

```
Rails.root.join('node_modules').to_s
```

> will this have any unintended consequences in my application?

I don't think so. Paths are converted to strings when loader searches for your files.